# Yosemite Sleep Wake Failure

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, sleep-wake

I've got a MBA Mid 2013 and since installing Yosemite, I've had 3-4 sleep wake failures.  Generally I'll close the lid, head home and either when I open the laptop at home or back at work the next morning I get message (not sure of exact text) "Your computer failed to wake properly and has restarted".  It didn't happen with Mavericks nor ML before that.

2 Times it stated the process was Activity Monitor and this most recent time it was airportd.

I don't really lose anything since all my apps open pretty much where they left off it's just a big annoying.

Any ideas?

https://gist.github.com/dstarh/77180ee3382cdca03afb

Comment: We could guess a lot, or have you help us to help you. Open the Console log (located in your Utility Folder), then find the "Wake reason Lid open", and copy the lines after that (about 30 lines) in here.

Comment: @Buscar웃 added a gist of the lines from console. Went above and below.

Comment: Just added the crash report as well

Comment: Ha thanks, any insight is appreciated.  As I said to this point it's not been critical but quite an annoyance.

Comment: Your sleep image has a lots of stuff in it :), lots of it is non Apple apps. For example Amazon Music and the VPN LogMeIn Hamachi ect.. that is normally OK, but ? Also the Console log was not long enough. From line 29 11/17/14 9:27:41.000 PM need much more info up to the line when system restarts. Just copy/paste them don't worry about the size of it. Of course do it after it happens :)

Comment: This is diagnostics only. Paste following in Terminal syslog -k Sender kernel -k Message CSeq 'n Cause: -' | tail | awk '/:/{$4=""; print}' | pbcopy  if there was a output from this it will be copied to your clip board. Paste the answer in your question. It should show the shutdown cause.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this happen a few times myself.  If I was to guess, at the time you closed you lid on your computer you had the power supply hookup and running. After the lid was closed you removed the power plug.  Later you open the lid, without the power plug and it was a blank screen.  If this is your case, you have two options,

1. unplug first before closing the lid
2. plug into power before you open the unit later.

I have found if I give my Mac a few seconds after closing the lid, before removing the power, it will not freeze later when I open the lid.

Still not sure of the problem, just a work around that I found after a little time with this type of problem.

Comment: It's not freezing, when I open the lid it's at the login screen, not the lock screen.  It shows my main account and the guest account because it has restarted.  I log in as normal and I then get the message that it has restarted

Comment: I've been doing #1 and it's not been happening but I can't say if thats it or not

Answer (score 0):

I have a 2010 MacBook Air, and it was freezing on wake from sleep --- making the thing basically useless.  Had to power cycle every time I used it.

After much research and fix attempts, here's what worked:
- reset PRAM
- reset SCM
- Use time machine to make a complete backup
- Reformat the hard drive
- Restore from the latest backup (I did NOT reinstall a fresh Yosemite -- I only restored)

The restore ran overnight (over wifi).  And after logging in, I had to input my iCloud password and a few other things, but my MacBook Air has all the files (for two users) and programs installed, and works great again.  Wakes from sleep like a champ.

So, my vote is: go full-on thermonuclear and wipe/restore.